# Undefined reference even though header file is included

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-errors, include, ebpf

In short, my `xdp_pass_user.c` won't compile for some reason which I don't understand (you might  be able to skip `xdp_pass_kern.c` in order to solve it).

In more detail, I'm trying to implement some eBPF logic. I have this `xdp_pass_kern.c` which is my kernel program:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <asm/byteorder.h>
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/udp.h>
#include <linux/pkt_cls.h>

#define SEC(NAME) __attribute__((section(NAME), used))

#define htons(x) ((__be16)__constant_swa16((x)))

struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") my_map = {
    .type        = BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY,
    .key_size    = sizeof(uint8_t),
    .value_size  = sizeof(uint8_t),
    .max_entries = 1,
};

SEC("xdp")
int xdp_prog_simple(struct xdp_md *ctx) {
    void *data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;
    
    struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr *)data;
    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)(eth + 1);
    struct udphdr *udph = (struct udphdr *)(iph + 1);

    /* sanity check needed by the eBPF verifier */
    if ((void *)(udph + 1) > data_end)
        return XDP_DROP;

    /* skip non UDP packets */
    if (eth->h_proto != __constant_htons(ETH_P_IP) || iph->protocol != IPPROTO_UDP)
        return XDP_DROP;
    
    /* Skip non port 1900 */
    if (ntohs(udph->dest) != 1900)
        return XDP_DROP;
    
    uint8_t key = 10;
    uint8_t *val = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&my_map, &key);
    if (!val) {
        val = (uint8_t *)(iph + 1);
        bpf_map_update_elem(&my_map, &key, &val, BPF_ANY);
    } else {
        if (*(uint8_t *)(iph + 1) != *val)
            return XDP_DROP;
    }
    
    return XDP_PASS;
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

And this `xdp_pass_user.c` which is my user program and uses (hopefully somewhat correctly) the program in `xdp_pass_kern.c` in order to attach the program to an interface and run `xdp_prog_simple` on each packet.
`xdp_pass_user.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <bpf/libbpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <linux/if_link.h>



static int if_idx;
static char *if_name;
static __u32 xdp_flags = XDP_FLAGS_UPDATE_IF_NOEXIST;
static __u32 prog_id;
static struct perf_buffer *pb = NULL;


static int do_attach(int idx, int fd, const char *name)
{
    struct bpf_prog_info info = {};
    __u32 info_len = sizeof(info);
    int err;
    err = bpf_xdp_attach(idx, fd, xdp_flags, NULL);
    if (err < 0) {
        printf("ERROR: failed to attach program to %s\n", name);
        return err;
    }
    err = bpf_obj_get_info_by_fd(fd, &info, &info_len);
    if (err) {
        printf("can't get prog info - %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return err;
    }
    prog_id = info.id;
    return err;
}


static int do_detach(int idx, const char *name)
{
    __u32 curr_prog_id = 0;
    int err = 0;
    err = bpf_xdp_query_id(idx, xdp_flags, &curr_prog_id);
    if (err) {
        printf("bpf_xdp_query_id failed\n");
        return err;
    }
    if (prog_id == curr_prog_id) {
        err = bpf_xdp_detach(idx, xdp_flags, NULL);
        if (err < 0)
            printf("ERROR: failed to detach prog from %s\n", name);
    } else if (!curr_prog_id) {
        printf("couldn't find a prog id on a %s\n", name);
    } else {
        printf("program on interface changed, not removing\n");
    }
    return err;
}

static void sig_handler(int signo)
{
    do_detach(if_idx, if_name);
    perf_buffer__free(pb);
    exit(0);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int prog_fd, map_fd;
    struct bpf_program *prog;
    struct bpf_object *obj;
    struct bpf_map *map;
    int err;
    
    char filename[] = "xdp_pass_kern.o";
    obj = bpf_object__open_file(filename, NULL);
    if (libbpf_get_error(obj))
        return 1;
        
    prog = bpf_object__next_program(obj, NULL);
    bpf_program__set_type(prog, BPF_PROG_TYPE_XDP);
    err = bpf_object__load(obj);
    if (err)
        return 1;
    prog_fd = bpf_program__fd(prog);
    map = bpf_object__next_map(obj, NULL);
    if (!map) {
        printf("finding a map in obj file failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    map_fd = bpf_map__fd(map);
    if_idx = if_nametoindex("lo");
    if (!if_idx)
        if_idx = strtoul("lo", NULL, 0);
    if (!if_idx) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid ifname\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if_name = "lo";
    err = do_attach(if_idx, prog_fd, if_name);
    if (err)
        return err;
    if (signal(SIGINT, sig_handler) ||
        signal(SIGHUP, sig_handler) ||
        signal(SIGTERM, sig_handler)) {
        perror("signal");
        return 1;
    }
    
    while (true)
        ;
        
    return 0;
}
```

First, I'm trying to compile the kernel program using:
`sudo clang -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -O2 -target bpf -c xdp_pass_kern.c -o xdp_pass_kern.o -w`. It compiles just fine.

Then, I'm trying to compile the user program with:
`gcc -o xdp_pass_user xdp_pass_user.c`
In order to eventually run with `./xdp_pass_user`. The compilation fails with this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccCZPdeQ.o: in function `do_attach':
xdp_pass_user.c:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `bpf_xdp_attach'
/usr/bin/ld: xdp_pass_user.c:(.text+0xc1): undefined reference to `bpf_obj_get_info_by_fd'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccCZPdeQ.o: in function `do_detach':
xdp_pass_user.c:(.text+0x16d): undefined reference to `bpf_xdp_query_id'
/usr/bin/ld: xdp_pass_user.c:(.text+0x1b0): undefined reference to `bpf_xdp_detach'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccCZPdeQ.o: in function `sig_handler':
xdp_pass_user.c:(.text+0x24e): undefined reference to `perf_buffer__free'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccCZPdeQ.o: in function `main':
xdp_pass_user.c:(.text+0x2a7): undefined reference to `bpf_object__open_file'
/usr/bin/ld: xdp_pass_user.c:(.text+0x2b7): undefined reference to `libbpf_get_error'
/usr/bin/ld: xdp_pass_user.c:(.text+0x2dc): undefined reference to `bpf_object__next_program'
/usr/bin/ld: xdp_pass_user.c:(.text+0x2f3): undefined reference to `bpf_program__set_type'
/usr/bin/ld: xdp_pass_user.c:(.text+0x2ff): undefined reference to `bpf_object__load'
/usr/bin/ld: xdp_pass_user.c:(.text+0x31e): undefined reference to `bpf_program__fd'
/usr/bin/ld: xdp_pass_user.c:(.text+0x337): undefined reference to `bpf_object__next_map'
/usr/bin/ld: xdp_pass_user.c:(.text+0x366): undefined reference to `bpf_map__fd'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit statu
```

As could be seen here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/tools/lib/bpf/libbpf.h#L207, those functions (e.g. bpf_object__load) are found in libbpf.h, which I include in my code:
`#include <bpf/libbpf.h>`.

I have also installed `libbpf-dev` and `libbpf0`.
It is unclear to me why I get this error even though I have the header file included.
Will appreciate any help.

Comment: That's a linker error, has nothing to do with the headers.  It suggest that gcc can't find `libbpf` ... try `gcc  -o xdp_pass_user xdp_pass_user.c  -lbpf`

Comment: P.S.: You may also want to have a closer look at your compiler's warnings...

Comment: First, why are you using sudo to invoke a compiler? I don't see why you need to give root privilege to a compiler. Second, why are you trying to link object outputs of clang and gcc? why not stick to one compiler?

Comment: @mASOUD For the second question, because within the BPF ecosystem, Clang is required to compiled kernel part and gcc remains most often used to compile the loader part.

Comment: Did you confirm that gcc is including the correct `libbpf.h` file?